# What puja or god to worship be done to lessen insults and loss of image in community per Hindu scriptures, to improve rAjapUjya and sat-keetri?

Tags: worship, puja

What stotras or pujas or yangya worship should be done to improve *rAjapUjya* and sat-keetri (honored and respected by others)? This is asked by someone who keeps getting blamed for doing things which he did not do or had no role in, repeatedly. Lately such rumored gossip also has damaged his image in society and he lost respect and friends/relatives over the past 6 years. No matter how much he is trying to put forth the truth no one is willing to even listen to him or take his side.

Comment: It's better to omit the explanation part regarding what has happened to the person since that will make the question a "personal advice"one. Just keep the part asking for improvement of reputation.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Mahabharata passage that suggests that doing some kind of spiritual practice like repeating the Gayatri mantra would be helpful.

> Markandeya answered, ‘There are three kinds of purity, viz., purity in
> speech, purity in deed, and purity achieved by use of water. He that
> has recourse to these three kinds of purity, attains, without doubt,
> to heaven. That Brahmana who adoreth the goddess Sandhya in the
> morning and the evening, and who recites meditatively the sacred
> goddess Gayatri who is the mother of the Vedas, sanctified by the
> latter, is freed from all his sins. Even if he accepts in gift the
> entire earth with her oceans, he doth not, on that account, suffer the
> least unhappiness. And those heavenly bodies in the sky including the
> sun that may be inauspicious and hostile towards him soon becomes
> auspicious and favourable towards him in consequence of these acts of
> his, while those stars that are auspicious and favourable become more
> auspicious and favourable in consequence of such conduct of his.’

**Mahabharata, Vana Parva, Section CLXLIX**